# No Wifi after installing XUbuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless, xubuntu

After not being able to solve my issue with XUbuntu 16 LTS (kept freezing indefinitely after running multiple tabs of Youtube, see post history for more info if needed) I decided to try my hand at an earlier release of Ubuntu.

After installing xubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64 I noticed I cannot access any of my Wifi networks. It says wifi is activated.

Running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` gives:

```
Network controller [0280]: Intel Corp Device [8086:3165] (rev 79)
Subsystem: Intel Corp Device [8086:4410]
```

My laptop is a Dell Inspiron 11-3157.

**Edit 1**: This laptop has no Ethernet adapter.

**Edit 2**: [I looked into this thread since it was similar to my issue. The settings are not picking up my "additional drivers", however.

#### Solved by upgrading to an Ubuntu version with 4.2 Kernel, however a separate issue (same as my previous posting here) occurs again after opening about 20 tabs of youtube videos to test it I get this [behavior](https://youtu.be/_PVN6_tkAQU).

Comment: Thanks for including the relevant output from `lspci`. I'll ping the wireless experts, chili555 and Pilot6, and hopefully they'll be able to help you!

Comment: Can you see WiFi networks? If so, can you just not connect to them?

Comment: @KazWolfe I cannot see the WiFi networks at all. I have several other laptops up and running on the networks just fine.

Comment: 14.04 does not support the adapter. You need the 4.4 kernel and the firmware.

Comment: @Pilot6 Installing w/ Ubuntu 15.10 with the 4.4 kernel solved the Wifi issue. After opening about 20 tabs of youtube videos to test it I get this behavior:

Comment: 15.10 is not supported anyway. It is off-topic.

Comment: I do not see any "issue" in the video. And 15.10 does not have the 4.4 kernel. All is unclear.

Comment: @Pilot6 You're right it's a separate issue, I will open a new thread. I did mention the wrong kernel- I think it's using 4.2.

Comment: @Pilot6 The issue is the operating system locking up after having heavy usage (such as 20-35 tabs of youtube open). I am only able to power cycle to exit out of that state. I have tried Ubuntu 16.04 with no luck either.

Comment: 15.10 is not supported at this site. There is no need to ask about it, the question will be closed. It looks like you do not have enough RAM for many tabs.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yep I will refrain from opening that thread in that case. This is only happening on the Ubuntu partition, I can open just as many on the Windows 10 with no issue. I have 4gb of RAM installed. I did not expect it to completely lock down the system in that manner, I expected maybe slowing down instead.

Comment: @operationcwl - You really should get more RAM. It's so cheap nowadays. About $50 for 8GB.

Comment: @AndroidDev I'm not sold that the issue is the RAM since this works fine on the Windows partition. I primarily use this light netbook to do development and school work. I don't have needs for any intense word processing or video games either- I have a desktop to do so on.

Comment: @operationcwl - Can you pull up the System Monitor application and watch the RAM usage as you open more and more tabs?